# Родственны ли слова "сквер" и "скверна"?

Tags: этимология

Ясно, что слово "сквер" произошло от английского "square" - площадь, но откуда тогда русские слова "скверна", "скверный"? Неужели, просто такое случайное совпадение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно случайное. А что ещё можно предположить в отношении пары слов, одно из которых явно недавнее заимствование, а второе в русском существует с незапамятных правславянских времен?! 
Да и корневое Н само по себе уже исключает предположение о родственности.

Значение морфа "скверн" - грязь, нечистое; а так же скаредный, жадный.

Answer (score -2):

Конечно не случайное. Случайных совпадений не существует. Однако эти два слова удалены друг от друга на огромное цивилизационное расстояние.  Слово  Скверна, по моим исследованием  вытекло  из литургического Зороастризма в изначальном виде xwarena и значении "сияния". Однако как и со многими другими изначально положительными словами,  разделались наступившие на протяжении двух последних тысячелетий  новые религии, перевернув их значение до  гнусного и еретического, так  случилось и с этим. Соотношение же с площадью, это тайный смысл этого литургического слова, который кривыми путями перекочевал вероятно вместе с римлянами или древними германцами в современный английский.